# Delete N/A when using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to bring the values from Sheet2 to Sheet1 using VLOOKUP formula (in VBA, after using the formula I copy paste in order to just see the value). But when the cells from Sheet2 are empty I get the "#N/A", which I don't want. What can I do to get the cell empty if there isn't any value, like replace the #N/A with nothing.

I have tried using the IFERROR formula, but I get 0 instead of nothing.

```
comm.Range(.Cells(2, "C"), .Cells(lr, "C")).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Sheet2!C[-2]:C[22],3,0),"""")"
```

Comment: Works fine for me. You will get a `0` if the cell has a `0` else you will get a "blank value"

Comment: What happens if you actually try that formula directly in a cell?

Comment: @Zac if works by using it directly in the cell, but I cannot. The client uses an userform to complete the empty data after the VLOOKUP, this is why I used it in VBA, because after I copy paste it to remove the formula

Answer (score 1):

- You could use *=**IFNA*** instead of *=**IFERROR*** because the code in case of error generate **#N/A** error.
- Lastly, in your formula after the number of column you want to return (in your case column number 3) you use number **0** instead of **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

The below code is not the answer but a sample of the formula.

**Code Sample:**

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$D$1:$E$2,2,FALSE),"") 'In excel

.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R1C4:R2C5,2,FALSE)" 'In VBA
```

Comment: In excel, TRUE and FALSE are treated as 1 and 0 respectively.  I use 1 and 0 for the true false portion VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP all the time without issue.